# How to use ternary operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My case is like this:

```
...
success:function(data) {
    jQuery.each(data.SearchCityResponse.Nation.City, function(key,value) {
        console.log(value.CityCode);
        city.append(jQuery("<option value.CityCod==\'CEB\')?\'selected\':\'\'></option>").val(value.CityCode).text(value.CityName));
    });
    city.select2();
}
...
```

I check in console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/haiBS.jpg

This seems like a problem writing ternary

Comment: You can't put Javascript operators of any kind in the middle of a string definition.  They are just part of the string when you do that.  Use logic to define the pieces of the string and then use string concatenation to build the final string.

Comment: Where is the ternary?

Comment: `city.append(jQuery("<option " + (value.CityCod == 'CEB') ? 'selected' : '' + "></option>").val(value.CityCode).text(value.CityName));`

Comment: The ) after \'CEB\') is closing off the jQuery statement. Try removing it to see if that works

Comment: There is no problem with the ternary operator. The problem is that you're not using one. Those `?` and `:` are parts of a string, the output is what is expected.

Comment: @jeff no, it's not. That's all in the middle of a string literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"<option value.CityCod==\'CEB\')?\'selected\':\'\'></option>"` is just a string and it'll not parse any variable or the JavaScript operator.

Also, there is typo, `CityCod` should be `CityCode`.

You can use concatenation `+` operator

```
"<option " + (value.CityCode === 'CEB' ? 'selected' : '') + "></option>"
```

Or, the selected status can be kept in a variable and that variable can be used.

```
var selected = value.CityCode === 'CEB' ? 'selected' : '';
"<option " + selected + "></option>"
```

You can also use the `prop()` to set the `selected` status.

```
$("<option />")
    .val(value.CityCode).text(value.CityName)
    .prop('selected', value.CityCode === 'CEB');
```